# Will regular queries use "FULLTEXT" indexes?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've got a somewhat large table on a database (~900k lines). I created fulltext indexes on some fields in order to be able to be able to use `MATCH(name) AGAINST(%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)` filters. It goes lightning fast and that's cool.

But when I query that very same field with a plain old `name = %s`, it takes more than 2-3 seconds to compute the query.

Am I doing something wrong or is SQL really not using the FULLTEXT indexes in regular queries?

Edit:

Short answer: **No, regular queries do not use FULLTEXT indexes.**

Somehow, I did not find that StackOverflow post during my researches. Hope this post will help lead people to the original question.